# Просьба написать комментарии к JS-коду

Tags: javascript, counter

Скинули скрипт, но без комментариев не понятно как он работает. Просьба сделать комментарии.

```
<button id="counter">Нажми на меня</button>
<script>
var b1 = document.getElementById('counter'), 
clicks = {}; 
function click(e) { 
  var id = e.target.id;
  if (!clicks[id])
    clicks[id] = 0;
    clicks[id]++;
    e.target.textContent = clicks[id];
}
b1.addEventListener('click', click);
</script>
```

Comment: Какая строчка вам непонятно и почему? Учебники по javascript читали?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Вас заминусовали, прискорбно, вот возможные комментарии)

```
//Кнопка
<button id="counter">Нажми на меня</button>
<script>
//получаем элемент с id="counter"
var b1 = document.getElementById('counter'),
//пустой объект в котором собираются или клики или кликнутые элементы 
clicks = {}; 
// функция вызываемая при клике на кнопке с id="counter"
function click(e) { 
//показывает на каком элементе сделан клик е(это событие объект Jquery.target, его метод)
  var id = e.target.id;
//если  не кликали то id = 0, и записи в объект(clicks) не происходит;
  if (!clicks[id])
    clicks[id] = 0;
//инкремент
    clicks[id]++;
//Вывод названия(контента) кликнутого элемента
    e.target.textContent = clicks[id];
}
// вешаем событие и вызываем ф-ию click
b1.addEventListener('click', click);
</script>
```

Comment: Не используйте смайлы в комментариях в коде. То что кажется Вам смешным, может не быть таким для следующего разработчика.

Comment: _е(это событие объект Jquery.target, его метод)_ - но ведь тут не используется jquery

Comment: "... и вызываем ф-ию click" - где?

Comment: _//пустой объект в котором собираются или клики или кликнутые элементы_ - так клики или кликнутые элементы?

Comment: "если  не кликали то id = 0" - ?? но это еще не точно (

Comment: `//Вывод названия(контента) кликнутого элемента` - но ведь выводится не название и даже не контент

Comment: Минус от меня за комментарии, не соответствующие действительности.

Comment: не понимаю, за что столько минусов, я лишь попытался ответить человеку.
Код писал не я.Я не могу знать досконально за что отвечает та или иная "каракуля".И потом почему  е не может быть event, строчка e.target.id наводит на мысль, что подключен jquery к странице.Ответ принят создающим вопрос.А , всё равно минусуют другие.Не сильно понятно.А впрочем ладно минуса, я то переживу, напишите свой ответ человеку.В чем проблема?

Comment: e.target.id это не показатель подключенного jQuery

Comment: А, здесь и не говорилось что это 100% Jquery. либо этот гений назвал похожей переменной e(е -общепризнанное обозначение Event, или я не прав) некий объект или это jquery потому что e.target позволяет узнать на каком элементе был сделан клик;Смысл в препирательстве я не вижу.Или напишите по факту, что есть что, и  признаю, что я не прав, и замолчу или не утруждайтесь  набирать какой нибудь ответ в стиле: "Я не могу обосновать свой комментарий, поэтому автору ответа  минус к карме".Я зашел сюда чтобы помогать, а не ловить минуса к карме, и не затевать "холивары".

Comment: Вам указали на Ваши ошибки и не с целью сказать что Вы плохой, а с тем чтобы сообщество SO получило наиболее верный ответ. Если Вы думаете что "e это общепринятое название евента" только для jQuery, и никоим образом не имеет такой же нативный объект js, то Вы не правы

Comment: да, я и не злюсь, пытаюсь лишь получить у Вас обоснованную,  аргументированную критику.И не против, чтобы сообщество получило наиболее верный ответ.Я только за.P.S и всё же  у нас возник консенсус, что е - в данном коде это event.Осталось узнать, что же за таинственная строчка target.textContent = clicks[id]